# Does not Hasse-Weil theorem hold in curves with no rational points?

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

According to Hasse-Weil theorem (see, for example, Silverman, Tate,
*Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, Theorem 4.1) we have:

> If $C$ is a non-singular irreducible curve of genus $g$ defined over a
>   finite field $F_p$, then the number of points
>   on $C$ with coordinates in $F_p$ is equal to $p + 1 - \epsilon$,
>   where the "error term" $\epsilon$ satisfies $|\epsilon| \leq 2g\sqrt{p}$.

For my surprise, I found very easily curves
satisfying (in principle) the conditions of the theorem but have no rational
points. For example, I have used MAPLE to check that in $F_7$, the curve
$$C := {x_{1}}^{3} - 2\,{x_{1}}^{2}\,{x_{3}} + {x_{1}}\,{
x_{2}}^{2} + 3\,{x_{1}}\,{x_{2}}\,{x_{3}} + {x_{1}}\,{x_{3}}^{2}
 - {x_{2}}^{3} - {x_{2}}\,{x_{3}}^{2} + {x_{3}}^{3}$$
(with $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ the projective coordinates), has no rational points.
However $C$ is irreducible, non-singular, and of genus $g=1$, and accordingly it seems to meet the conditions in the thorem above, so it should have at least two points, since
$8 - 2\,\sqrt{7} > 2$.
It has none, though.

What am I missing?

Comment: According to my recollection and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_a_general_field) *the formal definition of an elliptic curve is a non-singular projective algebraic curve over K with genus 1 and endowed with a distinguished point defined over K.* In other words, for the curve to be called elliptic, it needs to have at least one $K$-rational point. In Weierstrass form the point at infinity is often that *distinguished point*. I'm afraid I don't remember the proper terminology for curves without $K$-rational points.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen very late on this one, but in case you were still interested, the terminology for a genus $1$ curve $C$ without a point is a "torsor under $E$" where $E$ is the jacobian of $C$ (equiv. a "principal homogeneous space" for $E$). If you know the order $n$ of $[C] \in WC(E/K)$ then you could call it an $n$-covering.

Answer (score 1):

According to Magma, and assuming I typed it correctly, your curve is singular, hence the theorem doesn't apply.

```
> P<x,y,z>:=ProjectiveSpace(GF(7), 2);
> f:=x^3-2*x^2*z+x*y^2+3*x*y*z+x*z^2-y^3-y*z^2+z^3;
> Curve(P, f);
Curve over GF(7) defined by
x^3 + x*y^2 + 6*y^3 + 5*x^2*z + 3*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 6*y*z^2 + z^3
> RationalPoints(Curve(P, f));
{@ @}
> IsSingular(Curve(P,f));                                                                  
true
> Genus(Curve(P,f));
0
```